# How to interpret continuous variables in a decision tree model?

Tags: decision-trees, xgboost

After fitting a decision tree with some continuous variable, how do I interpret the effect that variable has on the target?

For example I'm predicting target Y. From sklearn random forest or Xgboost I can find out that the feature X is important. How do I determine if feature X's correlation to Y is positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient or the Spearman rank [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) coefficient between feature X and target Y. The [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) coefficient quantifies the direction and strength of the linear or monotonic relationship between the two variables.

A positive [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) coefficient indicates a positive relationship between feature X and the target Y, while a negative [correlation](https://databasecamp.de/en/statistics/correlation-and-causation) coefficient suggests a negative relationship. The magnitude of the coefficient indicates the strength of the relationship.